# Regular expression replace using Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have several comments in my `javascript` file that use the `//` syntax. I want to change it to `/* */` syntax.

So, if I have a comment like:

`// This is a comment`, I want it changed to

`/* This is a comment */`

So far, I am able to select all the comments using the regex `//.*`, but am unable to do a proper replace. Any help ?

Comment: regex: `//(.*)` and replace it with `/* $1 */`

Comment: @myusuf Whichever regex you end up using, make sure your code is version controlled or backed up, since it's likely you'll mess up some things that aren't comments (e.g. a string containing a URL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
//([^\r\n]+)
```

By

```
/*$1 */
```

Comment: Actually in Sublime Text you can search for only `//(.*)$`, it will work. And you can replace `\r\n` by `\v`which stands for all vertical spaces.